# Add class to a table cell if another cell contains a value

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I would like to add via javascript a class to a table's cell if another cell into another column contains a certain value. I am using a plugin to generate the table and datas comes from a JSON file, so I cannot edit the HTML code of the table.

For example if a cell in the "Company" column contains "Ernst Handel" I would like to add a class  `.custom-class` to another cell in the same `tr`, in my case to the cell "Austria" in the column Country.

What I tried is:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
   if($('td:contains("Ernst Handel")', this).length && $('td:contains("Austria")', this).length){       
        alert('here');
        $(this).addClass('custom-class');
    }
});
```

Here a sample:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.custom-class {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

here a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50otaz64/2/)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
$(this).addClass('custom-class');
```

`this` points to the whole row, not the `td`, so basically you are adding the class name to the `tr` element. If the cell you want to select is always in the third column like your example, then one way to target it is by using `nth-child`:

```
$(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").addClass('custom-class');
```

```js
$('tr').each(function(){
   if($('td:contains("Ernst Handel")', this).length && $('td:contains("Austria")', this).length){       
        alert('here');
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").addClass('custom-class');
    }
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.custom-class {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```